# Dropdown list binding issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, html-select, pageload

I have a placeholder which has some dropdownlist and a button, now this placeholder is initially hidden and when user makes any search on the page, based on that the placeholder gets visible and the dropdownlist gets filled, this is working absolutely fine

Now the problem starts when i click on the button inside the placeholder (next to dropdownlist), at this point of time, all the dropdownlist gets blank. I understand first page load executes and because there are no bindings (as dropdowns are binded on search click) it would make it blank, but i am not getting once the dropdown has been binded why it would matter for the page load to unbind it. Here's my code:

```
Page Load:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            plcView.Visible = false;
        }
    }

Search Button Click:
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!AppGlobal.IsSanadCompleted(AppGlobal.Sanads.Amma, txtITSId.Text))
            {
                lblErrorMessage.CssClass = "dnnFormMessage dnnFormWarning";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "You need Amma Sanad to attempt for Hifz Program.";
                plcView.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                plcView.Visible = true;
                txtJuz.Text = (Hifz.GetLastJuzAttempted(txtITSId.Text) + 1).ToString();
                drpAyahFrom.DataTextField = "Key";
                drpAyahFrom.DataValueField = "Value";
                drpAyahFrom.DataSource = objHifz.GetAyahListForHifzProgram(Convert.ToInt32(txtJuz.Text));
                drpAyahFrom.DataBind();

                drpAyahTo.DataTextField = "Key";
                drpAyahTo.DataValueField = "Value";
                drpAyahTo.DataSource = objHifz.GetAyahListForHifzProgram(Convert.ToInt32(txtJuz.Text));
                drpAyahTo.DataBind();

                drpGrade.DataSource = AppGlobal.GetGrades();
                drpGrade.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I even tried enabling EnableViewstate at page and also at skin (I am using Dotnetnuke) level, but still it does not makes any difference.

Can anyone please suggest where i would be getting wrong.

Comment: I'm going to guess you have to save the drop down content in a `Session` variable and re-populate it during `Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke is nothing but an ASP.Net app. So to look into your issue we have to delve into the [Page Life-Cycle of an ASP.Net page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events). There you will notice a Page_Event called [SaveStateComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.savestatecomplete.aspx). You see, this is called just before the Render event(*At this event the page is displayed to the end user*). So any changes done after rendering the page **will not be saved** in to the ViewState by default. Since your DropDowns are blank during SaveStateComplete, after a PostBack you're getting empty DropDowns.

The solution is to forcefully save the DataSource in your custom ViewState. For ex. in your button click, add the following:

```
var obj = objHifz.GetAyahListForHifzProgram(Convert.ToInt32(txtJuz.Text)));
drpAyahFrom.DataSource = obj;
ViewState["myUniqueKey"] = obj;
```

Then at the Page_Load event, you can use:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        plcView.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ViewState["myUniqueKey"] != null)
        {
             drpAyahFrom.DataTextField = "Key";
             drpAyahFrom.DataValueField = "Value";
             drpAyahFrom.DataSource = ViewState["myUniqueKey"];
             drpAyahFrom.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

You may have to perform the casting as per the requirement.

Comment: Yes this i have given a thought, but the strange thing is a similar another page i have where i am doing same task, just instead of dropdown there is checklistbox, but it does not gets blank on page load.

Comment: i tried with viewstate but that didn't worked either, finally i used static variables, that seems to be worked, however i am still not able to get the value selected in the dropdown, because when anyone changes the value from dropdown, page postbacks, and as per the cycle again page load gets executes and re-bind the dropdowns, and so i never gets the selectedValue, is there any possible way i can get selectedvalue.